# Could not launch './qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory

Tags: android, node.js, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I followed everything in this link 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html 
and I installed `Genymotion` in `Android Studio`... But I'm struggling with the shown error below... Whenever I'm running `ionic run android` or `ionic emulate android`:

```
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
C:\Users\t\todo\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js 
C:/Users/t/todo
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\t\todo\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\t\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_23_x86
Waiting for emulator...
Could not launch './qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory
```

I'm really not getting how to rectify this part... any suggestion or help will be very grateful...

Comment: I think you up try this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43385567/7859928 it help

Comment: For Windows 10, a solution to this problem was this:
[Adding emulator path to Path in environment variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54022903/9216932)

Answer (score 25):

I'm using Android Studio 2.3 with SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 and my problem was solved installing "Android Emulator":

[image]

Comment: Thanks, fixed it for me.

Comment: In Android Studio, I found that under Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

Answer (score 8):

Try to add the emulator on your PATH.

```
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

I just installed "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" in Android Studio

> Tools > Android SDK Manager > SDK Tools

[image: In the picture you can see more information]

Answer (score 2):

Android emulator.exe path has been changed to /sdk/emulator folder on the newer sdk tools. ionic emulator command must be linked to older emulator.exe path so you should change related config file with new path.

I can't point which ionic config file is related with android emulator because i have never used ionic. But if you can change emulator.exe path with newer one, i am sure problem will gone.

Answer (score 2):

Win 10 : i could solve this issue in two steps
1- Enable VT-x in Boise.
2- Enable it at windows : control panel > programs > add feature>VT-x

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with you.

After I downgrade the Android SDK Tooks from 25 rc1 to 24.4.1 . The error has gone.

Answer (score 1):

This also solves the error `qemu-system-i386.exe: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument`.

I had *Android Emulator* checked but not *Intel x86 Intel Accelerator (HAXM installer)*.  When I checked this option too, HAX initialized correctly. Error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)* already installed with a check mark next to it and everything, but I still received that error.

So I then decided to uninstall the *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)*, close the SDK Manager, reopen the SDK Manager and then finally reinstall it again. Then it worked perfectly.