# Issue starting android emulator in windows for nativescript

Tags: javascript, windows, nativescript

in my local windows dev machine I tried to start my android emulator to start working with nativescript, after adding an avd with advmanager I tried to start the emulator but I get the following error:

```
C:\Android\android-sdk>emulator @test
[5456]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch 'C:\Android\android-sdk\..\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266247/could-not-launch-qemu-windows-x86-64-qemu-system-i386-exe-no-such-file-or-d) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554337/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulatorqt-library-not-found) ?

Answer (score 0):

Install Android SDK and emulator. Need to set the environment path in the system variable.

1. Set ANDROID_HOME in system variable
   [image]
2. Double click on the path and open edit environment variable window and set below the path.
   C:\Users\PCUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
   C:\Users\PCUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

[image]

Delete C:\Users\tonyhudson\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools because it will cause the error.